# is there a way in vuetify to adjust padding in data table?

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js, padding

There is a default table from the vuetify docs:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#expandable-rows

The default padding for the td and th elements is 16px left and right.

How can I change it to a lower value?

Thank you.

I tried adding custom css rules, but I am not good at doing that, especially if it works via frameworks

UPDATE 26/03:
I have added these rules:

```
<style>
  .custom-cell-padding > tbody > tr > td {
    padding-top: 4px; /* Adjust as needed */
    padding-bottom: 4px; /* Adjust as needed */
  }
</style>
```

and it is still 16px. If you click on the td elememt in a dev mode in crome, you will see this:

```
<td class="v-data-table__td v-data-table-column--align-start">DATA<td>
```

I have inspected what rule is responsible for that padding copied it and it worked!

```
<style>
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > th,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > th {
    padding: 0 4px;
    transition-duration: 0.28s;
    transition-property: box-shadow, opacity, background, height;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
</style>
```

But isn't it too heavy and inelegant? Maybe there is some better approach or even via vuetify native?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code segment showing your attempt.  This way, we can see what you are trying to do and provide assistance with that approach.

Comment: You can write some CSS to override the default padding in the table.

Comment: @devlincarnate - thank you for your suggestion, I have found a solution while doing that. But maybe there is a better way? 
IVOGELOV - thanks, that was actually what I was trying to do yesterday, but managed only today. I don't like overriding the Vuetify native styles, since it can break something that you don't expect. So I will leave that question open for a while, maybe someone will give me some more advice.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, that is the solution:

```
<style>
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > th,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > td,
  .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > th {
    padding: 0 4px;
  }
</style>
```